# How to crop a batch of images at different places in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a batch of images in shape `[batchsize,h,w,channel]`. And a batch of topleft points in shape `[batchsize,2]`.

I need to crop each image with a bounding box (let's say in size of [10,10]), with its corresponding topleft point.

Could any one have any idea about how to do it other than loop around the batch size?

Things already checked:

```
- tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad
```

however the image must be in `[h,w,channel]`

```
- tf.slice
```

however its beginning position must be a int

Answer (score 0):

**1. Import library:**

```py
import numpy as np
```

**2. Define sample data (replace with your actual data):**

```py
images = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(10, 200, 200, 3))  # Batch of images
topleft_points = np.random.randint(0, 180, size=(10, 2))  # Top-left points
box_size = (10, 10)  # Bounding box size
```

**3. Create slicing indices using broadcasting:**

```py
# Calculate bottom-right coordinates (inclusive)
bottomright_points = topleft_points + box_size

# Broadcast coordinates to match image dimensions
topleft_x = topleft_points[:, 0:1]  # Add a dimension for broadcasting
topleft_y = topleft_points[:, 1:2]
bottomright_x = bottomright_points[:, 0:1]
bottomright_y = bottomright_points[:, 1:2]

# Create slicing indices
slices = np.concatenate([topleft_x, topleft_y, bottomright_x, bottomright_y], axis=1)
```

**4. Perform vectorized cropping:**

```py
cropped_images = images[np.arange(images.shape[0])[:, None], slices[:, 0], slices[:, 1], slices[:, 2], slices[:, 3]]
```